# Node/Express cannot GET any of my html/js/css files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node/Express application. There is a client side app as well, with multiple html files and multiple js files. I am using WebStorm, and clicking on RUN. This prints out in the console:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.2.2\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\name\Downloads\Fall 2016\Web\thing\src\server\index.js"
Shuffle router is loaded
I am open
Example app listening on 8080
```

So the express part works.

However, when I go to "`http://localhost:8080/game.html`" I get `Cannot GET /game.html`. This happens for all css pages as well. I can open the html pages using the preview(?) button in Webstorm, but that opens "`http://localhost:63342/`".

My folder structure is this:

```
public 
  css
     style.css
  img
     card1.jpg
  js
     game.js
  game.html
src
  server
     routes
       shuffleRoutes.js
     index.js
```

My index.js starts with this snippet of code before defining some functions:

```
let express         = require('express'),
    bodyParser      = require('body-parser'),
    logger          = require('morgan'),
    _               = require('lodash');
let path = require('path');

    //redis, session
let app = express();
app.use(logger('combined'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/img',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/img')));
app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/js')));
app.use('/css',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));

app.get("/v1/game", require("./routes/shuffleRoute.js"));

console.log("I am open");
```

and has this at the end of the file

```
  let server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on ' + server.address().port);
});
```

My game.js doesn't have any reference to the index.js file.
My game.html file only has `<script src="./js/game.js"></script>`.

How do I fix the error of not getting anything when I run the Webstorm project and go to localhost:8080/game.html?

Comment: Seems strange, try adding a mount path, and see if that solves anything? -> `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: Doesn't work: I get this printed in the Webstorm terminal: 
`Example app listening on 8080
::1 - - [10/Oct/2016:19:04:34 +0000] "GET /public/game.html HTTP/1.1" 404 29 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [10/Oct/2016:19:04:38 +0000] "GET /public/game.html HTTP/1.1" 404 29 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [10/Oct/2016:19:04:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 13 "-" ....`

Comment: Well, try something else then, did you try `app.use(express.static('/public'));` for instance

Comment: I've tried that, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an endpoint for the express to use,

So you need to serve the game.html to that route:

Since you are rendering html you will need to use ejs.

So adding

```
 //configuration  
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//route
    app.get('/game',function(req,res,next){
     res.render('game.html');
    });
```

Now go to `localhost:8080/game`

This should show your game.html

Comment: which files do these go to?

Comment: In your index.js

The configuration should be after `let app = express();`

The route before  `app.get("/v1/game", require("./routes/shuffleRoute.js"));`

Comment: So I get this error when I go there `Error: Failed to lookup view "game.html" in views directory "c:\Users\username\Downloads\Fall 2016\Web\projectfolder\src\server\views"`

Comment: I think I have an alternative to my answer, change `app.use(express.static('public'));` to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` remove the code I told you to add previously

Comment: yeah, that is not working for me. I get `cannot GET localhost:8000/game` or `localhost:8000/game.html`.

Comment: You mean `localhost:8080` right? As you have defined your port as 8080

Comment: yes, typo. I did use 8080, and that's what it gave me.